# Liquibase 4.13+ dependency without opencsv dependency

Tags: liquibase

I tried to upgrade the liquibase version to 4.13 in my project, but when I tested it, I found a problem with loading csv data. It looks like the opencsv dependency provided with the liquibase dependency is missing. The following dependency helped to solve this problem. But my question is, why do I have to manually add it now?

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
      <version>5.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [v4.12.0](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/2903) opencsv.jar was moved. Rather than shading opencsv into the liquibase-core.jar, define it as a dependency in the shipped pom.xml and include it as a separate jar in the internal/lib directory.